Error bounding with Integral test
If $f$ is monotone decreasing to zero, continuous and pass in the integration test. Then I'm interested in
$$
S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n).
$$
The equation (1) at in Integral_test_for_convergence (wiki) says that

To me it doesn't make sense since this means that $|S - S_{N-1}| = \sum_{n=N}^\infty f(n)$ belongs to the interval
$$
\left\{ \int_N^\infty f(x) d x, f(N) + \int_N^\infty f(x) d x \right\},$$
but the size of this interval is $f(N) + \int_N^\infty f(x) d x - \int_N^\infty f(x) d x = f(N)$. In other words, if I want to evaluate for example $S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1.5}}
$ with an error smaller than $10^{-4}$ (note that, this series pass in the integral test), I just need to evaluate $f(N)$ until $f(N) < 10^{-4}$, which is not true for this problem and for all $f(\cdot)$ continuous, decreasing to zero and with $\int_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ finite. So where would the error be?

$f$ has to approach $0$ otherwise the series diverges and so the integral by the integral test

@temp, I has forget this assumption, thanks.
